# Messenger integration (Reply and install)

Tags: android, facebook, integration, messenger

i have sent my application to **Review** to facebook and it was accepted, but i didn't know how to integrate the code in my app so it can show " reply " or " install " when sharing from my application.

**PS: my application shares only text and not images or gif or videos**
this is the *code* i used, but it's not working, please tell me what i did wrong

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");


            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedText);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra("com.facebook.orca.extra.PROTOCOL_VERSION", 20150314);
            intent.putExtra("com.facebook.orca.extra.APPLICATION_ID", "[My_FbApp_ID_HERE]");

            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: Read about optimized integration at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android

Comment: I did, but it didn't work, can you please tell me what i did wrong in the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by using messengerUtils ( i still don't know why it didn't work with intent, even if it's written in the facebook docs that it works )

Comment: hi Samir, I' facing the same problem can you please share some code

Comment: @Karthik the problem was   `intent.putExtra("com.facebook.orca.extra.PROTOCOL_VERSION", '20150314');` instead of `intent.putExtra("com.facebook.orca.extra.PROTOCOL_VERSION", 20150314);` it should be a string not an integer ( and i'm really sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need to check if FB Messenger is installed using [PackageManager.getInstalledPackages(*)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages(int)). Iterate through list and in case you find `com.facebook.orca` you use a reply intent (just to send text to it), otherwise use an intent to open a its Play Store page: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca so that they can install it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but i guess you got me wrong, the problem i had is to show the reply button **in messenger** not in my application, and when they click it, itopens **my application** so they can write and share another **text**

Comment: This: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android#optimized_integration , sending content back to messenger section explains it.

Comment: i have read all the documentation but i couldn't make it work :(

Comment: Well, you should set mime type to text/plain and other parameters should correspond to data which you're sending

Comment: According to documentations text/plain is not supported as a mime type